# How to parse a nested json array in CI

Tags: foreach, json, var-dump

i am trying to parse the following json

```
{
"offerinfo": {
    "offername": "chaos",
    "offertype": "3",
    "brand": "1",
    "subbrand": "0",
    "categories": "1,2",
    "Tags": "4,6",
    "promotiontype": "1",
    "currency": "1",
    "promotioncode": "1",
    "offertitle": "1",
    "offerdescription": "ad",
    "addtionalterms": "asdasd",
    "retaildescription": "asdasd"
},
"media": {
    "video": "",
    "images": []
},
"availability": [
    {
        "airports": "1,4,6",
        "stores": "3,4,5",
        "startdate": "2014",
        "enddate": "3434"
    }],
"featured": {
    "categories": "",
    "slot": ""
}
```

}

COde for parsing is

```
    $json = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')),true);
        //print_r($json)."<br/>";
        //var_dump($json);

        foreach($json as $key=>$value)
        {
            var_dump($value);
            $offername = $value['offername']."<br/>";
            //echo $media = $value['video'];
            $mediaimage = $value['images'];
            foreach($mediaimage as $a)
            {
                //echo $a['MediaFile'];
            }
            //echo $avail = $value['airports'];
            echo $key->{'availability'};
            //var_dump($avail);
        //  foreach($avail as $b)
        //  {
            //  echo $b['airports'];
            //} 


            //var_dump($mediaimage);
        }
```

i got the offername etc those in ogger info dictionary, but i am unable to parse the information from availability

can some one kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

`$json['availability']` is an array so you can access it like this

```
foreach ($json['availability'] as $availability) {
    echo $availability["airports"];
    // etc
}
```